# typeof function fix / alternative

Tags: javascript

The `typeof` doesn't work perfectly well, `typeof null` returns on `object` for example. Is there any better alternative to this kind of improved alternative built-in or custom made ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You can check for null with `if (variable === null)`

Comment: A better alternative to `typeof` generally, custom or built in.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A better alternative to `typeof` sure, but for what?

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but `typeof` is an operator, not a function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See [Fixing the JavaScript typeof Operator](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/).

In a nutshell, you can use this function:

```
var toType = function (obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-zA-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
}

toType(null);   // -> "null"
toType({});     // -> "object"
toType([]);     // -> "array"
toType("asdf"); // -> "string"
toType(/asdf/); // -> "regexp"
// etc.
```

You should see the article for the specifics on why it works the way it does and exactly what you can expect from it. It will always return a string, just like `typeof`.

Comment: You could use `var toString = Object.prototype.toString; toString.call(obj).slice(8,-1)` which prevents from empty object creation